# How to create flat file XSD-schema for two level hierarchical data?

Tags: xsd, biztalk, flat-file

I am a newer in BizTalk and I must create an XSD-schema from a CSV-file:

[image: CSV-file]

As you can see, it includes header and orders. Every order has it's own order-header - row with name of the shop and filled `Period` field, but with empty `Quantity`, `Price`, `Cost` and `Currency` fields. Every order has few positions, which have filled all fields, except `Period`. Every order-header has `ItemNumber` = 0. How to create correct flat file schema in this situation?

```
OrderDate;OrderNumber;ItemNumber;DESCRIPTION_LONG;Quantity;Price;Cost;Period;Currency
30-04-17;9;0;Shop: McDonalds;;;;2017-04;
30-04-17;9;1;Double burger;2;5,99;11,98;;USD
30-04-17;9;2;Coca-Cola;2;2,19;4,38;;USD
30-04-17;10;0;Shop: Hunting and fishing;;;;2017-04;
30-04-17;10;1;Fishing rod;2;10,90;21,80;;USD
30-04-17;10;2;Bait;5;1,00;5,00;;USD
30-04-17;10;3;Hunting gun;1;999,00;999,00;;USD
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the best option is parse your Flat File to an XML without trying to 'force' the final structure, as Pieter said on before answer. Something like this:

```
<Root xmlns="http://BizTalkMassCopy.FlatFileSchema3">
  <Header xmlns="">
    <HeaderOrderDate>OrderDate</HeaderOrderDate>
    <HeaderOrderNumber>OrderNumber</HeaderOrderNumber>
    <HeaderItemNumber>ItemNumber</HeaderItemNumber>
    <HeaderDescription>DESCRIPTION_LONG</HeaderDescription>
    <HeaderQuantity>Quantity</HeaderQuantity>
    <HeaderPrice>Price</HeaderPrice>
    <HeaderCost>Cost</HeaderCost>
    <HeaderPeriod>Period</HeaderPeriod>
    <HeaderCurrency>Currency</HeaderCurrency>
  </Header>
  <OrderItem xmlns="">
    <OrderDate>30-04-17</OrderDate>
    <OrderNumber>9</OrderNumber>
    <ItemNumber>0</ItemNumber>
    <Description>Shop: McDonalds</Description>
    <Quantity></Quantity>
    <Price></Price>
    <Cost></Cost>
    <Period>2017-04</Period>
    <Currency></Currency>
  </OrderItem>
  <OrderItem xmlns="">
    <OrderDate>30-04-17</OrderDate>
    <OrderNumber>9</OrderNumber>
    <ItemNumber>1</ItemNumber>
    <Description>Double burger</Description>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    <Price>5,99</Price>
    <Cost>11,98</Cost>
    <Period></Period>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
  </OrderItem>
  <OrderItem xmlns="">
    <OrderDate>30-04-17</OrderDate>
    <OrderNumber>9</OrderNumber>
    <ItemNumber>2</ItemNumber>
    <Description>Coca-Cola</Description>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    <Price>2,19</Price>
    <Cost>4,38</Cost>
    <Period></Period>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
  </OrderItem>
  <OrderItem xmlns="">
    <OrderDate>30-04-17</OrderDate>
    <OrderNumber>10</OrderNumber>
    <ItemNumber>0</ItemNumber>
    <Description>Shop: Hunting and fishing</Description>
    <Quantity></Quantity>
    <Price></Price>
    <Cost></Cost>
    <Period>2017-04</Period>
    <Currency></Currency>
  </OrderItem>
  <OrderItem xmlns="">
    <OrderDate>30-04-17</OrderDate>
    <OrderNumber>10</OrderNumber>
    <ItemNumber>1</ItemNumber>
    <Description>Fishing rod</Description>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
    <Price>10,90</Price>
    <Cost>21,80</Cost>
    <Period></Period>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
  </OrderItem>
  <OrderItem xmlns="">
    <OrderDate>30-04-17</OrderDate>
    <OrderNumber>10</OrderNumber>
    <ItemNumber>2</ItemNumber>
    <Description>Bait</Description>
    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
    <Price>1,00</Price>
    <Cost>5,00</Cost>
    <Period></Period>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
  </OrderItem>
  <OrderItem xmlns="">
    <OrderDate>30-04-17</OrderDate>
    <OrderNumber>10</OrderNumber>
    <ItemNumber>3</ItemNumber>
    <Description>Hunting gun</Description>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <Price>999,00</Price>
    <Cost>999,00</Cost>
    <Period></Period>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
  </OrderItem>
</Root>
```

With a flat schema similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns="http://BizTalkMassCopy.FlatFileSchema3" targetNamespace="http://BizTalkMassCopy.FlatFileSchema3" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="Root" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="infix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="Header">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter=";" child_order="infix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="HeaderOrderDate" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="HeaderOrderNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="HeaderItemNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="HeaderDescription" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="4" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="HeaderQuantity" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="5" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="HeaderPrice" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="6" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="HeaderCost" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="7" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="HeaderPeriod" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="8" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="HeaderCurrency" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="9" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="OrderItem">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter=";" child_order="infix" sequence_number="2" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="OrderDate" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="OrderNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="ItemNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="4" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Quantity" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="5" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Price" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="6" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Cost" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="7" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Period" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="8" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Currency" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <fieldInfo sequence_number="9" justification="left" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And then use a map to obtain the final result, with grouping mechanism such as [Grouping in Biztalk Map Based on Multiple Elements](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Grouping-in-Biztalk-Map-42190f60)

Comment: The result format is correct, but incomming format is totally different than my. I am newer in BizTalk and I am not strong in transformations

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this using tag Identifiers (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalknotes/2013/02/05/flat-file-schema-creation-with-tag-identifiers-in-the-input-flat-file-repeating-in-a-random-fashion/ for an example), but I'm not 100% sure this would work without issues, since the identifier (ItemNumber = 0) is not in the beginning of the line. My experience shows me the Flat file disassembler probing has limited success in those cases.

My general recommendation to people in this case would be not to try and 'force' structure in your flat file schema, since obviously your flat file structure does not have it. What I see is that each line has the same structure/format. It's only functionally different.

From that perspective I would go for a Flat File schema matching your CSV-file structure (one type of record with comma-separated fields and with a newline as a line delimiter) and, from there, map to a schema which makes more sense functionally.

Comment: Actually it could works, because items' rows have filled **Currency** field, headers' rows - haven't. When I create flat file schema, BizTalk thinks, that these rows have different count of fields. But the problem is that my flat-file have a header, which brokes you algorytm of flat-file Schema's creation. How can I delete first row of my file before pipeline's convertation starts? Or how can I specify schema to skip this first row?

Comment: Oh, no. "Different fields count" works only during creating schema. In work it show correct result (identical number of fields)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is,

1. Create a source schema for parse your flat file.

   [image]
2. Create a destination schema for grouped result

   [image]
3. Create a map for group your source schema.

[image]

4. Add this Inline XSLT Scripts to your map

For the first script functoid

```xml
<xsl:key name="groups" match="Order" use="OrderNumber"/>
```

For the second script functoid

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="Order[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('groups',OrderNumber))]">
   <xsl:sort select="OrderNumber" order="ascending"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="OrderDate != 'OrderDate'">
            <Order>
               <OrderDate><xsl:value-of select="OrderDate/text()" /></OrderDate>
               <OrderNumber><xsl:value-of select="OrderNumber/text()" /></OrderNumber>
               <Description><xsl:value-of select="Description/text()" /></Description>
               <Period><xsl:value-of select="Period/text()" /></Period>
               <Items>
                  <xsl:for-each select="key('groups',OrderNumber)">
                     <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="ItemNumber > '0'">
                           <Item>
                              <ItemNumber><xsl:value-of select="ItemNumber" /></ItemNumber>
                              <Quantity><xsl:value-of select="Quantity" /></Quantity>
                              <Price><xsl:value-of select="Price" /></Price>
                              <Cost><xsl:value-of select="Cost" /></Cost>
                              <Currency><xsl:value-of select="Currency" /></Currency>
                           </Item>
                        </xsl:when>
                     </xsl:choose>
                  </xsl:for-each>
               </Items>
            </Order>
         </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>   
</xsl:for-each>
```

5. Test your map and get this output.

```xml
<ns0:Orders xmlns:ns0="http://BizTalkServerTestProject.FlatFileSchema6">
  <Order>
    <OrderDate>30-04-17</OrderDate>
    <OrderNumber>10</OrderNumber>
    <Description>Shop: Hunting and fishing</Description>
    <Period>2017-04</Period>
    <Items>
      <Item>
        <ItemNumber>1</ItemNumber>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <Price>10,90</Price>
        <Cost>21,80</Cost>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <ItemNumber>2</ItemNumber>
        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
        <Price>1,00</Price>
        <Cost>5,00</Cost>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <ItemNumber>3</ItemNumber>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <Price>999,00</Price>
        <Cost>999,00</Cost>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderDate>30-04-17</OrderDate>
    <OrderNumber>9</OrderNumber>
    <Description>Shop: McDonalds</Description>
    <Period>2017-04</Period>
    <Items>
      <Item>
        <ItemNumber>1</ItemNumber>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <Price>5,99</Price>
        <Cost>11,98</Cost>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <ItemNumber>2</ItemNumber>
        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
        <Price>2,19</Price>
        <Cost>4,38</Cost>
        <Currency>USD</Currency>
      </Item>
    </Items>
  </Order>
</ns0:Orders>
```

You can find full source code of the schemas and the map from this URL.http://blog.sarslan.com/group-source-schema-in-a-map/

Comment: Looks nice, but you have forgotten [the header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4h025.png) in flat-file schema during rebuilding solution. Also I've get an error: `The Scripting functoid, that connects to target node 'Order', has an error in its 'Xslt Call-Template' definition: 'There is not an xsl:template node at the root of the xslt.'`

Comment: You are right, I totally forgot the header row, I made changes for about it on XSLT script. I did not get this exception. For compare, you can download solution file from this http://blog.sarslan.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/BizTalkServerTestProject.rar